# Most efficient way in postgres to keep a column unique when that column value is an 84 byte text field?

Tags: postgresql

Planning on using a hash index, but I'd also like to efficiently keep the column unique and enforce this in the database.  However I don't really want to build a btree and double the size of my database (the whole table is a text field, a bigint, and an int).   Is there a way to write the constraint to combine the hash index with a comparison of the data field?  I know I can't use a UNIQUE qualifier on a hash index, but it would really be nice!  Is there a way to write a constraint that would use the use the index to get a unique constraint even if the index itself doesn't support it?

Postgres version 11+

http://rhaas.blogspot.com/2017/09/postgresqls-hash-indexes-are-now-cool.html

Comment: The only way to ensure uniqueness is to use a btree index. If you need it, you'll have to live with the bigger index size.

Answer (score 1):

**EDITED TO ADD (28 October 2021):**

This can be accomplished with an exclusion constraint to eliminate the need for a primary key column:

```
# create table faux_unique (
  data text not null, 
  exclude using hash (data with =)
);
CREATE TABLE

# insert into faux_unique values('abc');
INSERT 0 1

# insert into faux_unique values('def');
INSERT 0 1

# insert into faux_unique values('abc');
ERROR:  conflicting key value violates exclusion constraint "faux_unique_data_excl"
DETAIL:  Key (data)=(abc) conflicts with existing key (data)=(abc).

# update faux_unique set data = 'abc' where data = 'def';
ERROR:  conflicting key value violates exclusion constraint "faux_unique_data_excl"
DETAIL:  Key (data)=(abc) conflicts with existing key (data)=(abc).

# select * from faux_unique;
┌──────┐
│ data │
├──────┤
│ abc  │
│ def  │
└──────┘
(2 rows)
```

**ORIGINAL ANSWER, BELOW**

You can use a hash index to simulate a `unique` constraint with a `check` constraint, but you need a PK on the table or else the constraint will not be able to catch violations due to `update`.

```
create table faux_unique (id serial primary key, data text not null);

create index faux_unique_hash_idx on faux_unique using hash (data);

create function is_unique_check(v_data text, v_id integer) returns boolean as $$
  select count(*) = 0
    from faux_unique
   where data = v_data
     and id != v_id;
$$ language sql;

alter table faux_unique add constraint faux_unique_check check (is_unique_check(data, id));
```

Run some test data:

```
insert into faux_unique (data) values ('first'), ('second'), ('third');
INSERT 0 3

insert into faux_unique (data) values ('first');
ERROR:  new row for relation "faux_unique" violates check constraint "faux_unique_check"
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (4, first).

update faux_unique set data = 'second' where data = 'first';
ERROR:  new row for relation "faux_unique" violates check constraint "faux_unique_check"
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (1, second).

update faux_unique set data = 'second' where id = 1;
ERROR:  new row for relation "faux_unique" violates check constraint "faux_unique_check"
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (1, second).

insert into faux_unique (data) values ('fourth');
INSERT 0 1
```

Comment: Downsides: Can't reference the column in a foreign key constraint. Won't work with `ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE`.